# Submit button doesn't work in my django project

Tags: python, html, django

The submit button doesn't work.
Can't save in database

```
{% block content %}
<form class="" action="{% url 'post_create_url' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
         <div class="form-group">
            {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.label }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my views.py code

```py
class PostCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': form})


    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': bound_form})
```

and this is my form code

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()

        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create"')
        return new_slug`
```

Comment: Should work. What does the server log tell you?

Comment: You should provide your views

Comment: first check if your view gets data from browser and if it works correctly - problem can be rather in python code, not in HTML.

Comment: I think that's because your form is not valid, because if it's valid then you'll get an error saying something like `need a HttpResponse instead of Post`

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "the button doesn't work". What happens when you push it? Nothing *at all*? Or does the page refresh with no change?\

Answer (score 0):

class PostCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': form})

```
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if bound_form.is_valid():
        ### new_post = bound_form.save() That's the problem.
        bound_form.save()
        ###return redirect(new_post)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('new_post')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': bound_form})
```

Comment: have you tested it? because i added all the correction from your comment and it still doesn't work